# Error attaching device '0000:02:07.0' to DPDK

Tags: networking

I install the libdpdk-dev,but it still get error,do you finally fix the problem? My ubuntu version is 16.04,DPDK version is 19.11 and ovs version is 2.13.90. Looking forward to your reply！

The message is like this:
root@coco:~/dpdk-19.11/usertools# ovs-vsctl show
477daa7f-1eca-43c4-a2ba-0a53f3e5409b
Bridge br0
datapath_type: netdev
Port dpdk1
Interface dpdk1
type: dpdk
options: {dpdk-devargs="0000:02:07.0"}
error: "Error attaching device '0000:02:07.0' to DPDK"
Port dpdk0
Interface dpdk0
type: dpdk
options: {dpdk-devargs="02:06.0"}
error: "Error attaching device '02:06.0' to DPDK"
Port br0
Interface br0
type: internal

Comment: Sorry 16.04 is past EOL and not supported on this site.

Comment: @Coco can you please check the pcie port status with `lshw -c net -businfo` and `lspci -ks 0000:02:07.0`. The DPDK dev args passed is also incorrect.